# Onchange checkbox not updating when checked

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a checkbox in Wordpress, which is validating properly until the user doesn´t check the box.
Then it will remain acting as unchecked and will not allow to login again, showing allways the oninvalid message (no matter if it is checked or unchecked).

```
  <input type="checkbox" required id="accept_terms" name="accept_terms"
   class="validate[required]" value="1" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity ('Please...')">
```

I have also tried with onchange instead of oninvalid. Same problem.

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly. You're saying validation runs fine when the checkbox is not checked - warning the user that they must click it - but after the user clicks it, it still remains unchecked? Or is it checked, but after submitting the form, it fails to be detected as checked?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. It is your first statement, even if the user checks it, the checkbox will act as unchecked, except for the tick.

Comment: _"act as unchecked, except for the tick"_ - so validation still detects it as unchecked and disallows submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, it will also show the alert warning the user and never hide it once it has appeared.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259669/custom-html5-form-validation-errors-only-happen-after-first-attempt), it seems to deal with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had already checked it.  I wanted to avoid introducing or changing the JavaScript in this Wordpress. Finally found a solution, thanks again for your value answers.

Answer (score 1):

It only had a way to change validation state, adding `validity.valueMissing` solved it.

```
onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Please...
```